# Is there a way to display an error for the user when using NGINX limit conn module?

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

I am using http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html which works fine. But is there a way to warn the user of why they are being blocked?

I remember seeing sites with a message: "you can only download 1 file at a time".
Or something similar. How can that be done when using NGINX limit conn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the directive `limit_conn_status` returns a `503` which states gateway unavailable. You can do the following:

```
limit_conn_status 429;
```

`429` is the code for Too many Requests which then you can do

```
error_page 429 /too-many-requests.html
```

To give a custom look and feel for the status code.

Comment: This is very clever i'll give it go. Now i need to find a way to stop the limit from flooding my error log, but that's something else.

Comment: @MichaelRogers did this solution work for you? I tried to do something similar and it just doesn't seem to use by html page. For more context see https://serverfault.com/questions/1078250/nginx-error-page-not-working-for-ngx-http-limit-conn-module